# A weaker than "zero derivative" condition implies that a function is constant?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, reference-request

Let $f:(a,b)\to R$ be a continuous function such that $\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{|x_n-x_0|}\leq 0$ for every $x_0\in(a,b)$ and sequence $x_n$ converging to $x_0$ such that $x_n\neq x_0, n\geq 1$. Does this imply that f is a constant on $(a,b)$?

If this is a well-known fact, I would like to have a reference.

P.S. The previous version of the question had a misprint, allowing the trivial answer from Najib Idrissi (thank you for this).

Comment: As has been pointed out, $f(x)=-x$ is a simple counterexample. A better question might be to ask whether the hypothesis implies that $f$ is non-increasing.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi How's that? The function $f(x)=-x$ _is_ non-increasing.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In fact it seems to me that the revised version is a theorem, by a simple bisectioin argument. Say $x<y$ but $f(x)<f(y)$. Let $I_1$ = $[x,y]$. Let $I_2$ be the right half of $I_1$ or the left half, in such a way that the slope of the chord joining the endpoints is at least as large for $I_2$ as for $I_1$. Etc. The point in the intersection of all the $I_n$ is going to have that lim sup strictly positive.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Oh. You were referring to the OP's edit, not to my revised version of the question. Yes, the edit allows the same counterexample. Never mind...

Comment: In my original question, I forgot the absolute value in the denominator. In the corrected version, with $f(x)=-x$, we have $\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{|x_n-x_0|}=\frac{x_0-x_n}{|x_n-x_0|}$, and can take values $-1$ or $+1$ depending from whether $x_n>x_0$ or $x_n < x_0$. Hence, the limsup can be 1>0, and the condition does not hold.

Answer (score 2):

> **Problem** Let $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$  be a continuous function such that $$\limsup\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{|x_n-x_0|}\leq
>   0$$  for every $x_0\in (a,b)$ and every sequence $x_n$  converging to
>   $x_0$ such that $x_n\not= x_0$ for all $n$.   Does this imply that f
>   is a constant on $(a,b)$?

Note the absolute values in the denominator.  By an oversight, they were not present in the original posting
which explains the other comments and answer.  Properly stated now this is rather more interesting.

It is not hard to prove that the answer is "YES" 
as the sketch by Professor Ullrich illustrates, 
but the poster also wanted to know whether there is
any standard "well-known" result related to this.

The condition as stated is not very intuitive. [It looks like a derivative but for that pesky absolute value in the denominator.]
 But interpreted on the right-hand side of $x_0$ it merely asserts that
the upper right Dini derivative $D^+ f(x_0) \leq 0$. Interpreted on the left-hand side of $x_0$ asserts that
the lower left Dini derivative $D_- f(x_0) \geq 0$.  The way the problem is posed (without alluding to the Dini derivatives) is a bit perverse, but that is how we treat our analysis students to toughen them up for the real world.  Reposing the problem as a question about Dini derivatives is more conventional.  Also reposing this as a monotonicity problem, rather than a constancy problem, is also more instructive.

So this question reduces really to asking just this (which I prefer to flip around since I like all my monotonicity theorems to go up).

> **Lemma**. If $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$  is continuous and  $D_+ g(x) \geq 0$ for all $a\leq x < b$ then $g$ is nondecreasing.

[Here if $g=-f$ and $D^+ f(x) \leq 0$  then $D_+ g(x) \geq 0$.]

So the problem does reduce to this monotonicity lemma. Is that "well-known?"  Well no, but only because it is way too trivial.  The correct monotonicity theorem that is implicit here is due to Dini himself and is quite ancient if you agree that 1878 is ancient.

> **Theorem (Dini)**. If $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$  is continuous and  $D^+ g(x) \geq 0$ for all $a\leq x < b$ then $g$ is nondecreasing.

Using the *upper* Dini derivative instead of the (much easier) lower Dini derivative makes this    more interesting and more useful.

The standard modern reference is Saks, *Theory of the Integral*, pp. 203-204 where he gives, in addition to the original, a useful refinement due to Zygmund.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and references!